# Django: managing permissions, groups and users during data migrations

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-authentication, django-migrations

### Problem

During a data migration, I'm trying to create a `django.contrib.auth.models.Group` and some `User`s and then attaching said group to one of the users.

Problem I'm finding (other than the permissions still not being created, but I've already found a solution to that), is that for some reason the many-to-many manager doesn't seem to be working as it should (?).

Basically what I'm trying to do is something like:

```py
group = Group.objects.create(name="manager")
# user creation...
user.groups.add(group)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Group instance expected, got <Group: manager>
```

Whenever I try to replicate this in the Django shell, it works without any problem. It only fails while doing migration. Any ideas?

### Things I've tried and other information

- I've tried both populating the m2m relation through the `User` related manager and the `Group` related manager, that is, `user.groups.add(group)` and `group.user_set.add(user)`. Both give me a similar error.
- Just partially related, but just so I have the permissions needed, I have this first in my migration:

```py
for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
    app_config.models_module = True
    create_permissions(app_config, verbosity=0)
    app_config.models_module = None
```

- The group is supposedly created properly. Given that I create the groups and the users in different helper functions, I actually grab the group with `Group.objects.get(name="manager")`, and when printing, it shows the correct information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the problem comes up when you use the `django.contrib.auth.models.Group` model directly. If instead you use `apps.get_model("auth.Group")`, everything works fine.